# How can we store some data at end of PDF in %<<-- key --> {}?

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, file-handling

I discovered a pdf where the document stores some hash under this tag %<<-- start of key  --> {}

just before EOF. how to read and add any data in pdf in this way ?

Javascript or Python code to do this.

I opened the PDF with notepad,Before EOF I found this.

```
trailer
<<
/Size
58
/Root
4
0
R
/Info
5
0
R
>>
%<--Key-->{"H":"Mg4e5efnsewfru2i6wy15e6tw/Rhrq+Alsawuvjtetk=","P":[{"L":"R/Dowdrwirgsxtqcbrddlfybaxkbtvkv8jbvcbhwd8m="},{"R":"7qlbr2yrcvbnesviidgae8hj0ii6+Bnq5lzuxhpytoi="},{"R":"Xwikx4vkcxlnmob6g31zcxml1qiukppret/Yrcc1+L8="},{"R":"Piwql0ujqhkxeoj/Byu3kzkhdgv5chnf+Oqmrqims18="}],"T":"0x69c28199553e905298fdff8fddb741ae90db1735da1b7d62651fad4cd7dbdde9","N":"Polygon","R":"1a6h2kzir0sjktf5dgyy0yvjw+6mzse7xw5cckdwgui=","S":"Meqciaxeeldy3rdipghw7xqpvjqdtftdpugyfdwgbtftnry5aiafl9eog8jmivzjbtqrzwzcdse2c7z2jvg9tl9lqmmckw==","V":"2.0"}<--Key-->
startxref
227548
%%EOF
```

Comment: As far as the format pdf is concerned, that is a comment and, therefore, ignored by most pdf processors.

Comment: As @mkl mentioned this is a comment. Storing critical info in this way is close to being a moron because the next utility compressing the PDF will remove comments - and thus throw away these "data". PDF has many options to store central data, outside pages. First choice would typically be `EmbeddedFiles`.